# Link two tables on two different data sources servers not linked

Tags: sql, coldfusion

I am using SQL server and ColdFusion. I have two tables on different data sources. I am trying to link the first table with op_id and Closed_by to the second table to assoc_id. And in return know that assoc_id matches assoc_name on that table.

Basically I have an app where the user types there associate number for op_id when there submitting work I want op_id to link to assoc_id on the other table so I can know the name of that individual. Basicaly the same thing with Closed_by as well.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

```
<cfquery name="employeeID" datasource="officeweb">
            SELECT op_id, Closed_by
            FROM dbo.Dealer_Track_Work
        </cfquery>

       <!---<cfdump var="#employeeID#" label="getDetailsQuery1">--->

       <cfquery name="employeeName" datasource="tco_associates">
            SELECT assoc_id, assoc_name
            FROM dbo.tco_associates
        </cfquery>

       <!---<cfdump var="#employeeName#" label="getDetailsQuery1">--->

        <CFQUERY NAME="getDetailsUnion" DBTYPE="query"> 
         SELECT * FROM employeeName gt 
         inner join employeeID gd on get.op_id = gd.assoc_id 
         </CFQUERY> 

     <cfdump var="#getDetailsUnion#" label="getDetailsUnion">
```

Comment: you need to set up linked servers in SQL and then you can do `select a from dealer_track_work b inner join server_name.dbo.tco_associates c on b.id = c.id`

Comment: The only other way is to run 2 queries and join them together which will be very inneficient, but that's their choice to not link the servers.

Comment: you'll have to explain more than "it's not working"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Query of queries does not support JOINS or table aliases.

```
<cftry>
    <cfquery name="employeeID" datasource="officeweb">
        SELECT op_id, Closed_by
        FROM dbo.Dealer_Track_Work
    </cfquery>

    <!---<cfdump var="#employeeID#" label="getDetailsQuery1">--->

    <cfquery name="employeeName" datasource="tco_associates">
        SELECT assoc_id, assoc_name
        FROM dbo.tco_associates
    </cfquery>

    <!---<cfdump var="#employeeName#" label="getDetailsQuery1">--->

    <cfquery name="getCombinedDetails" dbtype="query">
        SELECT *
        FROM employeeName, employeeID
        WHERE CAST(employeeID.op_id AS integer) = CAST(employeeName.assoc_id AS integer)
    </cfquery>

    <cfdump var="#getCombinedDetails#" label="getCombinedDetails">

    <cfcatch type="any">
        <!--- Dump any error and abort the request --->
        <cfdump var="#CFCATCH#" label="cfcatchError" abort="true"/> 
    </cfcatch>
</cftry>
```

NOTE: if `tco_associates` or `Dealer_Track_Work` have a lot of data, this approach will be bad. If you are getting a specific ID, then you should filter by the ID in the first two queries so the database server isn't returning a large result set.

Comment: Given that you haven't provided any other code, I cannot say why you get a blank screen. You can try wrapping all the queries in a `cftry/cfcatch` and dump any error it catches. See [Error Handling in CF](http://www.learncfinaweek.com/week1/Error_Handling/)

Comment: I did read that the servers aren't linked. That's why there's two queries. And as I stated in the answer, you cannot use a JOIN in a query of queries. I've updated the code with a try/catch statement.

Comment: CF will throw an error if you try and compare different data types in a query of queries. This error indicates that the `assoc_id` (the right hand expression) is a string column, while `op_id` (the left hand expression) is an integer. I've updated the answer to use a CAST() in the QofQ.